# Fetching a graph object from my sql DB using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So I have a graph object that looks like this:

```
public class Graph
{
    ....
    public virtual Node RootNode {get;set;}
}

public class Node
{
    ....
    public virtual IList<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    ....
    public virtual Node SourceNode { get; set; }
    public virtual Node TargetNode { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping the entities using Fluent Nhibernate. It's pretty straight forward:

In `Graph`: `References(x => x.RootNode, "root_node").Not.LazyLoad()`

In `Node`: `HasMany(x => x.Nodes).Table("nodes")           .KeyColumn("graph_id").Not.LazyLoad().Inverse()`

In `Link`: `References(x => x.TargetNode, "target_node_id ").Not.LazyLoad()` and `References(x => x.SourceNode, "source_node_id")`

*Note: I want the load to be not lazy because I'm sending to the client the whole object anyway.

Using Nhiberante Profiler I checked what happens when I write `session.Get<Graph>(id)`.

**The Problem** was that it selects the objects from the DB (mysql) **one by one**. (selects the graph, then the root node, then the link, then the target and so on...)

**What I want**
 is for Nhibernate to select the graph, all the nodes, all the links (only 3 queries).

**What I tried**
is to add `public virtual IList<Node> Nodes { get; set; }` In `Graph` instead of the `RootNode`, And in `Node` add `public virtual bool IsRoot { get; set; }`
**It seems to work** but I don't like the `IsRoot` property because I want the graph to know which node is the root. it might also cause bugs (2 nodes with IsRoot = true).

Do you have any better solutions for this problem??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to store the graph Id in the node, and load all the nodes for the graph. Once all loaded it will use the cache to get child nodes instead of executing SQL statements.

```
public class Graph
{
    ....
    public virtual Node RootNode {get;set;}
}

public class Node
{
    ....
    public virtual Graph Graph {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    ....
    public virtual Node SourceNode { get; set; }
    public virtual Node TargetNode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that is what I tried. It worked as I said, but i still need to know which node is the root node.

Comment: Refer the updated answer, still Graph would point to root node, but again every node would have a reference to the graph, so you know the root node without having a special flag, and also you can load all nodes associated with graph in single query